# Django: Photologue does not show images in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, photologue

I am trying to install django-photologue. Everything seems ok, because I install and set up following the official guidelines. I have to upload some photos as examples. However, when viewing a photo or gallery details , then an error as follows:

```
Caught an exception while rendering: 'Photo' object has no attribute 'get_thumbnail_url'
```

I tried to remove the following code from the file **photo_detail.html**

```
{% if object.public_galleries %}
<h2>This photo is found in the following galleries:</h2>
<ol>
{% for gallery in object.public_galleries %}
    <li>{%previous_in_gallery object gallery%} <a href="{{ gallery.get_absolute_url }}">{{ gallery.title }}</a> {%next_in_gallery object gallery%}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endif %}
```

No more errors, but pictures do not show up. If you click on the link will still lead to correct photographs to see. I think the problem in:

```
{{ object.get_display_url }}
```

It is totally not return any value.
Please help me solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you run `python manage.py plinit` after install and opt to create both a `thumbnail` and `display` photosize? These photosizes need to be defined in your database.

Comment: in newer versions of `django-photologue` you need to run migrations: `python manage.py migrate photologue`

Answer (score 0):

Honestly from looking at the source, it looks like a bug in the project. If you [search the source](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=thumbnail+package:http://django-photologue%5C.googlecode%5C.com&exact_package=http://django-photologue.googlecode.com/svn), thumbnail doesn't seem to be a field within the Photo class (`get_FIELD_url` is an easy way to access an ImageField's url btw.) So I would recommend tinkering with the source or finding another project. I might be wrong though but that's what my ~5 minute scan of the project found.

Answer (score 0):

In other versions, you have to edit photologue/templates/photolog/tags/next_in_gallery.html and replace

```
{{ photo.get_thumbnail_url }}
```

with

```
{{ photo.thumbnail.url }}
```

Same for photologue/templates/photolog/tags/prev_in_gallery.html.